# How to get a Application specific Google Map api key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

How should i get **Application specific Google Map Api key** so that when i put my application on **Android Market** it work for every one who downloaded my Application. **What steps** i need to do so that my app works fine on every android device..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by "Application specific Google Map Api key" you mean a key for each copy of the app that is downloaded.

I don't believe each copy of your application needs a unique key.

"Because MapView gives you access to Google Maps data, you need to register with the Google Maps service and agree to the applicable Terms of Service before your MapView will be able to obtain data from Google Maps. **This will apply whether you are developing your application on the emulator or preparing your application for deployment to mobile devices.**"

From: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Just hardcode the key you're using to test into your app.

Comment: you got my point right. So if i hard code key in my app will it work with any device on which my application is installed.

Comment: Yes, the key should work when used anywhere by anyone (unless of course Google blocks it:: only happens if you do bad things).
I've never done GM on Android, but when I used it for a Blackberry app we had no issues using the same key for each install instance.



I believe the only common reason keys get disallowed is if you're trying to scrape their servers for data.

Answer (score 0):

> How should i get Application specific Google Map Api key so that when
>   i put my application on Android Market it work for every one who
>   downloaded my Application. What steps i need to do so that my app
>   works fine on every android device..

To register for a Maps API Key, you need to provide an MD5 fingerprint of the certificate that you will use to sign your application. Before you visit the registration page, use Keytool to generate the fingerprint of the appropriate certificate.
First, determine which key you will use to sign your application at release and make sure of the path to the keystore that contains it.

For Further assistance check out this
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint